# potential gfortran or openMP bug when using "omp if" and "reduction"

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I have a MWE where an omp reduction breaks if I add the option for GPU offloading (even if it isn't used).

I know I can do a work-around using preprocessor directives but I would really prefer to stick with an openMP solution.

When I run the code with `nvfortran` it works fine. When I run with `gfortran` it breaks.

compiler versions tried:

- `gfortran 10.3.0`
- `gfortran 11.3.0`
- `nvfortran 22.5-0` (from nvhpc toolkit)

I am using an `Arm Neoverse-N1` cpu and I have also tried on my local `Intel Core i7-7500U` cpu.

commands to compile:

- `GPU version - nvfortran` : `nvfortran -cpp -DUSEGPU -mp=gpu mwe.f90 && ./a.out`
- `CPU version - nvfortran` : `nvfortran -cpp -mp=multicore mwe.f90 && OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./a.out`
- `CPU version -  gfortran` : `gfortran -cpp -fopenmp mwe.f90 && OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./a.out`

Expected output:
**CPU Version**

```
$ nvfortran -cpp -mp=multicore mwe.f90 && OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./a.out
id= 0 i,j=  1 1 a_ij= 1.000 b_ij= 0.900 max_diff=0.100
id= 0 i,j=  2 1 a_ij= 2.000 b_ij= 1.800 max_diff=0.200
id= 0 i,j=  3 1 a_ij= 3.000 b_ij= 2.700 max_diff=0.300
id= 0 i,j=  1 2 a_ij= 2.000 b_ij= 1.800 max_diff=0.300
id= 0 i,j=  2 2 a_ij= 4.000 b_ij= 3.600 max_diff=0.400
id= 1 i,j=  3 2 a_ij= 6.000 b_ij= 5.400 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  1 3 a_ij= 3.000 b_ij= 2.700 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  2 3 a_ij= 6.000 b_ij= 5.400 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  3 3 a_ij= 9.000 b_ij= 8.100 max_diff=0.900
max_diff =  0.900
```

**GPU Version**

```
$ nvfortran -cpp -DUSEGPU -mp=gpu mwe.f90 && ./a.out
max_diff =  0.900
```

Output from gfortran:

```
$ gfortran -cpp -fopenmp mwe.f90 && OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./a.out
id= 0 i,j=  1 1 a_ij= 1.000 b_ij= 0.900 max_diff=0.100
id= 0 i,j=  2 1 a_ij= 2.000 b_ij= 1.800 max_diff=0.200
id= 0 i,j=  3 1 a_ij= 3.000 b_ij= 2.700 max_diff=0.300
id= 0 i,j=  1 2 a_ij= 2.000 b_ij= 1.800 max_diff=0.300
id= 0 i,j=  2 2 a_ij= 4.000 b_ij= 3.600 max_diff=0.400
id= 1 i,j=  3 2 a_ij= 6.000 b_ij= 5.400 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  1 3 a_ij= 3.000 b_ij= 2.700 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  2 3 a_ij= 6.000 b_ij= 5.400 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  3 3 a_ij= 9.000 b_ij= 8.100 max_diff=0.900
max_diff =  0.000
```

If I comment out the lines below (marked with `!<---- comment this`) and delete the work `distribute` from the line `!$omp distribute parallel do simd reduction(max:max_diff) collapse(2)` then it works as expected.

```
$ gfortran -cpp -fopenmp mwe.f90 && OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./a.out
id= 0 i,j=  1 1 a_ij= 1.000 b_ij= 0.900 max_diff=0.100
id= 0 i,j=  2 1 a_ij= 2.000 b_ij= 1.800 max_diff=0.200
id= 0 i,j=  3 1 a_ij= 3.000 b_ij= 2.700 max_diff=0.300
id= 0 i,j=  1 2 a_ij= 2.000 b_ij= 1.800 max_diff=0.300
id= 0 i,j=  2 2 a_ij= 4.000 b_ij= 3.600 max_diff=0.400
id= 1 i,j=  3 2 a_ij= 6.000 b_ij= 5.400 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  1 3 a_ij= 3.000 b_ij= 2.700 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  2 3 a_ij= 6.000 b_ij= 5.400 max_diff=0.600
id= 1 i,j=  3 3 a_ij= 9.000 b_ij= 8.100 max_diff=0.900
max_diff =  0.900
```

Am I mis-using the `if()` statement with openMP or is there potentially a bug with gfortran or openMP?

**mwe.f90**

```
program test

  use omp_lib

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: N=3 
  integer            :: i, j
  real               :: a(N,N), b(N,N), max_diff
  logical            :: is_GPU
  is_GPU = .false.
#ifdef USEGPU
  is_GPU = .true.
#endif

  !$omp target data if(is_GPU) map(to:a, b)
  !$omp target teams if(is_GPU)
  !$omp distribute parallel do simd collapse(2)
  do j = 1, N
    do i = 1, N
      a(i, j) = i*j 
      b(i, j) = i*j*0.9
    end do
  end do
  !$omp end target teams

  max_diff = 0.0 
  !$omp target teams if(is_GPU)     !<---- comment this
  !$omp distribute parallel do simd reduction(max:max_diff) collapse(2)
  do j = 1, N
    do i = 1, N
      max_diff = max(max_diff, abs(b(i, j) - a(i, j)))
#ifndef USEGPU
      write (*,'("id=",I2," i,j= ",2(I2)," a_ij= ",F5.3," b_ij= ",F5.3," max_diff=",F5.3)') &
        omp_get_thread_num(), i, j, a(i,j), b(i,j), max_diff
#endif
    end do
  end do
  !$omp end target teams     !<---- comment this

  write (*,'("max_diff = ", F6.3)') max_diff
  !$omp end target data

end program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bug... but a user error (see [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109701))

The following mwe will work (but it requires gfortran version >= 12.2.0)

```
program test

  use omp_lib

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: N=3 
  integer            :: i, j
  real               :: a(N,N), b(N,N), max_diff
  logical            :: is_GPU
  is_GPU = .false.
#ifdef USEGPU
  is_GPU = .true.
#endif

  !$omp target data if(is_GPU) map(to:a, b)

  !$omp target teams distribute parallel do simd if(target:is_GPU) collapse(2)
  do j = 1, N
    do i = 1, N
      a(i, j) = i*j 
      b(i, j) = i*j*0.9
    end do
  end do

  max_diff = 0.0 
  !$omp target teams distribute parallel do simd if(target:is_GPU) reduction(max:max_diff) collapse(2)
  do j = 1, N
    do i = 1, N
      max_diff = max(max_diff, abs(b(i, j) - a(i, j)))
    end do
  end do

  write (*,'("max_diff = ", F6.3)') max_diff
  !$omp end target data

end program
```